# Android Edit Text . Click on 'Next' to go the the next view and not the next edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have `4 edit texts` and a `radio button` and a `spinner`.

```
<EditText
 ... />

<EditText
 ... />

 <Radio
  ... />

 <EditText
   ... />

 <Spinner
   ... />


  <EditText
   ... />
```

I have used `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` for moving from one to the next.
The last edit text has `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`
As a result the focus moves from one edit text to another. But misses the radio and spinner in between.

***How do we move from `edittext` to other views as the user clicks on 'next'?***

Answer (score 1):

You can use android:nextFocusForward

Refer this 
http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation.html